# Timestamp from google analytics events getting rounded in Google Data Studio`

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to export some google analytics events from GCP BigQuery to Google Data Studio. The `events-timestamp` field is in milliseconds since epoch format. However when it is imported to Data Studio, it looses the precision and gets rounded to the nearest day at 12:00 AM. How do I handle the import correctly ?

Comment: The BigQuery field is timestamp or string?

Answer (score 2):

One way to display a *DateTime* field is to go to the Data Source and change the *Date* Type from the default `YYYYMMDD` to *Date Hour Minute* `YYYYMMDDhhmm`:

GIF to elaborate:

[image: 1]]

Comment: Thanks Nimitha. However my issue is that it is rounding to 12AM always.